# How can i create a keyboard listener in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, listener

I want to change the visibility of a particular layout when keyboard appears .How can i create a listener for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class for Soft Keyboard Detection

```
public class RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard extends RelativeLayout {

    public RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public interface Listener
    {
        public void onSoftKeyboardShown(boolean isShowing);
    }

    private Listener listener;

    public void setListener(Listener listener) 
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
        int statusBarHeight = rect.top;
        int screenHeight = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        int diff = (screenHeight - statusBarHeight) - height;

        if (listener != null) 
        {
            listener.onSoftKeyboardShown(diff>128); // assume all soft keyboards are at least 128 pixels high
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);       
    }
}
```

Extend your activity with RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard class and write below code in your activity

// To scroll layout when keyboard is visible

```
RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard mChkKeyBoradVisibility;
            mChkKeyBoradVisibility = (RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard)    mTabLogin_Layout.findViewById(your layout id);
            mChkKeyBoradVisibility.setListener(this);
```